# Are gold bag locations fixed in Infinity Blade 2?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

It's clear that gold bags are MUCH more prevalent in Infinity Blade 2 than they were with the original, not to mention more cleverly hidden. Do they always show up in the same places over multiple playthroughs? Alternatively, is there a fixed set of places that they can show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the first game, there are fixed places where gold CAN spawn, but it may or may not appear in a particular location in a given playthrough.

Also, sometimes a larger treasure trove may spawn (a group of three gold bags), and you an also occasionally find keys and health potions in these locations as well.

Comment: Keys in gold bags? Or do they show up as keys on the floor?

Comment: @Nick They show up as keys. It took me a while to realize what they were, and that they were lootable! (The models are kind of funky - you can check them out in the inventory/store screen so you know what you're looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

What I've noticed is there are times where gold bags only appear when the cinematic is showing. For example after the first fight in the Saranthia wilderness, where you chose to go to the dam or skip it. The cinematic shows you character, and behind you a gold bag (sometimes) appears to the right.

What I do is I tap on the spawn points just in case there is a small key hidden in there.